# When and where did "spanking" begin to be used as an adjective?

Tags: etymology

"That's a spanking car."

"A spanking little horse."

> Spank
>
> - t.v. - To beat across the buttocks with the open hand, to strike especially on the buttocks with the open hand.
> - i.v. - to move quickly, dashingly, or spiritedly
>
> Spanking
>
> - 1.remarkable of its kind, very good, excellent, smart in appearance. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spanking?show=0&t=1413215528
> - 2.brisk, fresh and strong http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spanking?show=0&t=1413216280

Comment: Etymonline.com is pretty good for this sort of thing: "1660s, "very big or fine," later (especially of horses) "moving at a lively pace" (1738), of uncertain origin; perhaps from a Scandinavian source (OED compares Danish spanke "to strut"). Probably also related to spanker "something striking" (for size, etc.), 1751; as a kind of sail from 1794."

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess (not a good idea, I suppose, in a question-and-answer format). Since the only use of the word *spanking* I am familiar with (besides the word denoting corporal punishment) is in the saying,

> "Brand spanking new,"

I think the linkage between spanking and newness comes from the delivery ward in a hospital. In other words, there is an obscure analogy hidden in the expression. The newness of, say, a new car is like a brand new baby whom a gynecologist or nurse spanks on the behind to get him or her breathing. The connection between the baby and the spank on the tushy is pretty well engrained in the American psyche, I believe.

By the way, another Americanism is "as cute as a baby's bottom," (or sometimes "smooth as a baby's bottom") which adds another wrinkle to the notion of brand spanking newness. Moreover, to this day, a common locution in America is to insert an emphatic--sometimes vulgar--word between two other words, or parts of words. An example:

> That's un--freaking--believable!

instead of saying simply

> That's unbelievable!

Go figure!

Comment: Your example "brand spanking new" is the only use of "spanking" as an adjective that sounds right to my American ears.

Comment: @JoelAnair: Thanks for the confirmation. I can now rest assured that my instinct was good. Don